# Creating a custom registration form in Google Course Builder

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, google-apps

I need to create a registration form for the Google Course Builder to be opened without a Gmail account and just register with the personal email using a customized registration form.

I checked the [Google Course Builder Website](https://code.google.com/p/course-builder/wiki/CreateRegistration) and I did find useful information about how to customize it except that I do not know much Python. like where to write my new entities "your email :" for example and how to link it to the HTML form. Or how to disable the navigation for the Gmail login form when registering. Like the one created in [Coursera Website](https://accounts.coursera.org/signup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for someone without a GMail account to register, but they will have to create a Google account linked to their e-mail address.  They can do that by going to https://accounts.google.com/Login and clicking the red Sign Up button on the top-right.

If you add some fiends to the form in views/register.html, their data will get saved in the Student model in the data store, JSON encoded in the 'additional_fields' property.  That's never been useful to me, and I've added more fields using python, but yeah.

Comment: And about using Gitkit or Firebase? I am trying to configure Gitkit but I run in a 400 error page after follow this tutorial here: https://github.com/pabloppp/Course-Builder-gitkit-setup-guide

I'm using version 1.10 and the tutorial were created for version 1.9.

Comment: Sorry Alex, I don't know anything about the newer versions of Course Builder or about GitKit.  Good luck!